# Run function before a fetch call?

Tags: javascript, html, css, fetch

I've been attempting to create a vanilla js weather app, that takes the users location with there permission and inputs it into the fetch call upon there acceptance as a template string, the weather app would than deduce there location and give the temperature back.

Im still relatively new and i've hit a roadblock, i've noticed that the fetch call runs before the user is able to click the button that allows there location to be taken.

is there anyway to pause the fetch call until after the function runs? can i run the fetch call with the onclick attached to the function?

```
    var latitude,longitude;
function allow() {
navigator.geolcation;
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(currentPosition);
};

function currentPosition(position) {
latitude = (position.coords.latitude);
longitude = (position.coords.longitude);
};

function onPositionReady() {
    console.log(latitude,longitude);
    // proceed
};     

let api  = {
key:'456fa9bb93098fb3454b25380512d491',
};

fetch(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=${latitude}&lon=${longitude}&exclude=minutely,hourly,daily&appid=${api.key}&units=imperial`)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    // Here's a list of repos!
    console.log(data)
  });
```

Comment: Put the fetch call in a function and call that function after user clicks the allow button.

Answer (score 0):

Try this below.

If you're successful in gaining permission to get the users location, then thats when the long/lat becomes available. At the same time as they become available, you can then run your fetch call.

If the users deny's you using the location, then it will trigger the `error` function.

Learn more here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition

```
function success(pos) {
  var crd = pos.coords;
  let api  = {
    key:'456fa9bb93098fb3454b25380512d491',
  };

  fetch(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall? lat=${crd.latitude}&lon=${crd.longitude}&exclude=minutely,hourly,daily&appid=${api.key}&units=imperial`)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    // Here's a list of repos!
    console.log(data)
  });
}

function error(err) {
  console.warn(`ERROR(${err.code}): ${err.message}`);
}

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options);
```

If you don't explicitly want to have the fetch directly in the `success()` method for the sake of readability (under the assumption you're going to add more code to it), you could wrap it in its own function outside of the success function and call it in the `success()` function instead like this

```
function doRequest(crd) {

  let api = {
    key: '456fa9bb93098fb3454b25380512d491',
  };

  fetch(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall? lat=${crd.latitude}&lon=${crd.longitude}&exclude=minutely,hourly,daily&appid=${api.key}&units=imperial`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      // Here's a list of repos!
      console.log(data)
    });
}

function success(pos) {
  var crd = pos.coords;
  doRequest(crd)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your success and failure callbacks don't look right either -- they're defined but never used. Depending on how the API is secured, you may not want to publish your API key publicly -- so a non-interactive example:

```
var options = {
  enableHighAccuracy: true,
  timeout: 5000,
  maximumAge: 0
};

function success(pos) {
  var crd = pos.coords;

  console.log('Your current position is:');
  console.log(`Latitude : ${crd.latitude}`);
  console.log(`Longitude: ${crd.longitude}`);
  console.log(`More or less ${crd.accuracy} meters.`);

  fetch(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=...`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      // Here's a list of repos!
      console.log(data)
    });
}

function error(err) {
  console.warn(`ERROR(${err.code}): ${err.message}`);
}

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options);
```

Comment: This will fail, you have incorrect variable names in the fetch endpoint.